# Getting 404 error while deploying asp.net core web api on azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am deploying ASP.net core web api on azure app service.I am using asp.netcore 3.1.2.Routing is not working on Azure.It's working perfectly fine on localhost. I am stuck on this for long time.Please Help.

This is my controller class:

```
[Route("login")]
[ApiController]
public class LoginController : ControllerBase
{
    #region Private Fields

    private readonly ILoginService _loginService ;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Parameterized constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="loginService">loginService instance</param>
    public LoginController(ILoginService loginService)
    {
        _loginService = loginService;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used to authenticate the user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="accessToken">Google access token</param>
    /// <returns>If user is authenticate then return the username, email, JWT token 
    /// else Invalid request </returns>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("{accessToken}")]
    public IActionResult Login(string accessToken)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(_loginService.Authenticate(accessToken));
        }
        catch (CustomException exception)
        {
            return StatusCode(exception.ErrorDetails.StatusCode, exception.ErrorDetails);
        }
    }
```

This is my startup.cs
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("ApiCorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        }));

        services.AddValidationParameters(Configuration);

        string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<SampleContext>(options => options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.SwaggerConfiguration();

        services.RegisterSyncServiceDependencies()
                .RegisterServiceDependencies();

        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RollingProjectionAndDeploymentContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();
        }

        app.UseCors("ApiCorsPolicy");

        app.ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint(Constant.SwaggerEndPoint, Constant.SwaggerTitle);
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
```

This is running without any error in local machine.But when I deploy it to azure 404 error page is returned.

Comment: diid you navigate to kudu console and check what went wrong?

Comment: We're going to need a bit more information. Try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have given my project's controller and startup.cs class.